# Why share the use of the ampersand (&) for both address operator and the reference declarator?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, standards, ampersand

In C++, the ampersand character (`&`) can be used to get the address of an lvalue, a function designator, or a qualified name . .

```
int y;
int* p_to_y = &y;
```

The character has a shared use in C++ as  a reference declarator . .

```
int y;
int& y_alias = y;
```

When learning C++ after having a cursory knowledge of C, this double usage caused me a lot of confusion! I understand that the context in which the symbol is used makes all the difference, but given that references and pointers are important concepts that should not be confused, can anyone suggest why the `&` was recycled rather than using a new alternative symbol?

Comment: -1 & voted to close as not constructive, unless someone finds a log of the original draft of C++ where this was contemplated, this is just guessing or giving your own arguments (that can make sense), not the actual reason (which could even be: "why, that looks easy to me, and I don't wont to use a new symbol!".

Comment: In C, `*` can be used to dereference a pointer, declare a pointer, and multiply values. Why did that not confuse you?

Comment: There is just so much in C and C++ that is stupid in hindsight. We could waste months going over it. And at this point it is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @interjay - because pointing and arithmetic operations are easier to distinguish

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, I didn't want to sound like I was calling it stupid! I was a legit question that has intrigued me

Comment: It just doesn't work as a question here. It's like asking why the default function return type is `int` instead of `void`, or why there are so many levels of operator precedence, or why nested assignment (`a = b = c`) was allowed, which leads to the need for `==` and all the bugs that created, or why have both prefix and suffix forms of `++` and `--`, or null-terminated strings instead of length bytes, which leads to buffer overflows and disallows strings from also containing arbitrary binary data, or... or...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't worry, you'll get over this confusion soon enough.

There can be multiple reasons:

- logically, they are somehow connected. A reference behaves like a pointer, which is the address of an object.
- Not a lot of free symbols. Looking at my top row of the keyboard, I can only see... well, only `$` and `@`. I personally wouldn't like either, but that's maybe just because I got used to `&`.
- The counter-reason you provided can be regarded as a pro-reason - as to not add another symbol to the language. Think about it - most symbols available in C++ are also available in C. The intention could have been for a smooth learning curve from people migrating from C. And since `&` is logically connected to the concept of reference, it's the most suited.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer to what I believed was a reasonable question (obviously the rest of the community believes I wanted to start some kind of debate). I'm not confused any more, but it was a particular hurdle for me in the past

Comment: @learnvst I actually happen to agree, it's not really a constructive question (at least for this site), but I do find it interesting. Never thought about it before.

Comment: Now that I know that there was no fundamental reason that I was missing, I can see that the question could spiral into debate. There is no rationale easily available on the web, so I asked the question here. I was shocked to see the speed at which the CLOSE hammer came down, but at least I have a clue now. +1 / Accept

Answer (score 6):

> can anyone suggest why the `&` was recycled

Because `&y` and `int&` both are "about addresses" in some way: one creates a pointer, which is a thin abstraction of a memory address, and the other indicates a reference, which is like a pointer that can never be null.

Comment: I'm wondering why this was downvoted, apart from "there are only so and so many symbols available" this answer seems perfectly good to me. Though of course references _are not_ pointers, they still share most properties (and are most of the time implemented as pointers by the compiler, internally).

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1. This question seems to have stirred up bad vibes :(